# Render Background based on Tumblr tag

Tags: javascript, html, css, tumblr, tumblr-themes

I want to know is it possible to render backgrounds based on tags in Tumblr?

What I mean is, I post about general life and about a Book Series I like, I want it to be that when I post a quote about life, the background colour is black and when I post a quote about the book, the background colour is blue.

Is this possible and if so, how?

Answer (score 2):

You can add a custom attribute or class to the element you want to change his background with jQuery with something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var tag = $('select the element where your tag is').text(); 
/*If there are more than one tag you'll have to work with 
the string to select //only the one you want, maybe with 
a switch if you have a limited number of options*/
  $('body').addClass(tag);
})
```

Then, with css you can change it with a selector like this:

```
body.tag{
   background: #yourcolor;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add to your posts the class `{TagsAsClasses}`. Then tag all life posts with "life" and book posts with "book".

Then you can style like this:

```
.life { background-color: black; }

.book { background-color: blue; }
```